# Review bar Element links/actions are not clickable

Tags: bug, design

When scrolling, the review bar element is shown below question/answer section elements.
Example from "First Post" queue

[image]

Example from "Late Answers" queue

[image]

z-index of `js-review-bar` should be increased.

Browser: Google Chrome, version 80.0.3987.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Comment: Please include Browser and OS versions...

Comment: status-review on Meta SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344041/tags-tabs-and-the-timeline-button-flow-over-review-completion-panel-when-scrol

Comment: Temporary fix is to install my userscript [ReviewQueueHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ReviewQueueHelper.user.js)